# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\PAVANS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tess_rwsvvy4k.pdf'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

###### My Requirement

I have generated an exe from python code using  **pyinstaller**. Since I am using **pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr**  OCR operation **Tesseract** is the dependency. So I have added tesseract folders in spec file and generated the exe. My aim is to bundle tesseract folders inside the exe itself, so that tesseract folders will be copied in Temp files when I open the exe.

###### What have I done so far

I have successfully generated the exe from python code. When I open the exe the bundled tesseract files will be extracted to temp files directory and I can start using the tesseract.

###### Issue

Generally when we run **pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr** it will create a pdf (i am passing **extension='pdf'** parameter) in temp folder with some random name **tess_rwsvvy4k.pdf**. This works when I run code directly. But when I am running exe, it is not generating the pdf file in temp folder.

###### Error from Log file

```
  File "PDF to Readable.py", line 216, in start_conversion
  File "pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 446, in image_to_pdf_or_hocr
  File "pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 290, in run_and_get_output
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\PAVANS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tess_rwsvvy4k.pdf'
```

###### Spec file

```
....
a = Analysis(
    ['PDF to Readable.py'],
    pathex=[],
    datas=[],
    binaries=[('Source/poppler-0.68.0/bin/*', 'poppler-0.68.0/bin'),
            ('Source/poppler-0.68.0/include/poppler/cpp/*', 'poppler-0.68.0/include/poppler/cpp'),
            ('Source/poppler-0.68.0/lib/pkgconfig/*', 'poppler-0.68.0/lib/pkgconfig'),
            ('Source/poppler-0.68.0/lib/*.*', 'poppler-0.68.0/lib'),
            ('Source/poppler-0.68.0/share/man/man1/*', 'poppler-0.68.0/share/man/man1'),
            ('Source/TESSEERACT-OCR/*.*', 'TESSEERACT-OCR'),
            ('Source/TESSEERACT-OCR/doc/*', 'TESSEERACT-OCR/doc'),
            ('Source/TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/*.*', 'TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata'),
            ('Source/TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/configs/*.*', 'TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/configs'),
            
            ('Source/TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/tessconfigs/*.*', 'TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/tessconfigs')],

.....
```

Guide me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I made a small mistake in spec file. Original `tessdata\configs` folder contains 25 files and `tessdata\tessconfigs` folder contains 6 files. But due to my mistake I got only 5 files in `tessdata\configs` folder. So I missed dependencies for `hocr`. So in my case I could not able to generate `pdf`.

###### My Mistake

```
('Source/TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/configs/*.*', 'TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/configs'),
            
            ('Source/TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/tessconfigs/*.*', 'TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/tessconfigs')
```

###### What I have changed

```
('Source/TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/configs/*', 'TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/configs'),
            
            ('Source/TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/tessconfigs/*', 'TESSEERACT-OCR/tessdata/tessconfigs')
```

So this will add all the files from the `tessdata\configs` and `tessdata\tessconfigs` folders. And I have got my desired output.